# What was the first device to "beep" in lieu of tactile feedback to button presses?

Tags: history, sound, design-choices, human-computer-interface

I'm splitting this question off of [When was beeping invented, in a user interface sense?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20332/when-was-beeping-invented-in-a-user-interface-sense) because I think it's more answerable on its own and I suspect likely to still be computing-related.

At some point in the past, all electrical switches would have provided only natural/"real" feedback. The physical mechanism of the switch itself would click or clunk or rattle or thud. Some switches were intentionally designed to incorporate e.g. tactile domes or other mechanisms to make this feedback more pronounced, and I suppose other switches could have been designed oppositely for quiet/unnoticed activation.

But eventually switches weren't just controlling simple electric loads directly but had additional *electronics* in between or instead. This correlated with — and probably even caused! — buttons becoming smaller and less physical, since they could now switch circuit-level voltages instead of load-level currents. With something like a cheap momentary switch or elastomeric keypad or membrane keyboard there is very little physical feedback and it is ambiguous whether/when the button is actually pressed. So it became fairly common for an electronic device to include additional logic/circuitry to give a little "beep" sound to confirm for its user what a physical "click" or "snap" would have provided from a different style of switch.

What was the first user interface that used an auditory beep solely to confirm that a button had been activated? (Things like telegraph keys or car horns or musical instruments don't count since making the sound *itself* is the purpose of activating the circuit.) Was this kind of feedback part of a computer or microcontroller system or did the idea happen already in the days of analog or basic digital circuitry?

Comment: While interesting, I do not really see the relation to retro-COMPUTING here. Asking for 
 UI feedback implementation is a generic UI-design question, which itself is a topic of design and not specific to computing.

Comment: @Raffzahn What if I changed the question to "was a computer the first device to beep to signal button presses…?" Same potential answers, but more on-topic?

Comment: Not really, as that obviously includes asking for non computer as well - keyboards aren't something exclusive to computers. Beside that, it might really be better suited for a design related audience, don't you think so? (Don't get me wrong, I do think it's a quite interesting research and would love to learn some answers, just not really fit here)

Comment: That question is for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: FWIW, my guess would be a capacitive sensor elevator keypad, suitable for (government-owned) buildings with residents prone to vandalism. Plastic buttons didn't last long, and metal buttons would frequently be stuck. I speak from experience.

Comment: Your comment about telegraph keys is not quite accurate.  The purpose of a telegraph key is to produce a sound at the remote end of the wire.  Any sound produced locally would be a secondary effect, one that might be useful to confirm that the key press had been sensed.

Comment: @LeoB. You must have grown up in (former) SU countries, right? I have seen that elevators :)) In Germany it would have been the contrary. Sensor buttons in elevators were kind of the super high class stuff of the early 1970s, seen in prestigious company buildings :))

Comment: The first time I've heard a "beep" in response to a button press had absolutely nothing to do with computers in a traditional sense of the word - it was on a microwave oven with the cheapest variety of membrane switch buttons, absolutely lacking any kind of tactile feedback.

Comment: @moonwalker That almost certainly was a computer in the traditional sense of the word - input (buttons, door switches), output (turn on/off magnetron, beeps, display time), storage (small ROM program, a few bytes of RAM for time, power level, etc.). Likely a 4-bit or 8-bit CPU/microcontroller. The microwave ovens before computer controls used electromechanical timers, relays, etc. - not much different from other older electric ovens.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: The original purpose of a telegraph key was to produce marks on a ribbon at the remote station.  The fact that the equipment produced sounds that a skilled operator could decode by ear was an unintentional side effect.

Comment: @Raffzahn Right. In Moscow, sensor buttons in the elevators were also not very widely used (only in rather prestigious districts of the city, just in case). Soviet teenagers had too much time on their hands regardless of the social stratum.

Comment: @LeoB. Yeah. In fact I never have seen any in ordinary houses in ex-SU. Always plastic buttons about a mm too small pointing in random directions :) But I wouldn't put it too much on teenagers alone. It seems to me a mentality issue. A complete neglect of any common structure. 'cause there is an unbelievable difference between a hallway and the apartment - heck, even the outer apartment door is complete different on both sides. I've seen many new (last 20 years) buildings, were they never really finished the hallways.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact sorry, I guess I missed the "general purpose" part in front of "computers in a traditional sense of the word".